# Significant difference of nutrients among soil types with lme. Is soil depth a fixed effect?

Tags: anova, fixed-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I have a soil nutrient dataset of 60 plots from three different soil types divided per three depths.

I did a one way ANOVA for every nutrient at the first depth and I got nice results in which I can see some nutrients changing among soil types and some other no.

Now I would like to get a significance value for difference in soil nutrients among soil types, but considering even soil depths, and maybe plot as a random factor.

As far as I am aware ANOVA can’t include a random factor, so I tried with `lme` model in R. If I include soil depth as a fixed effect it happens that all the elements have a significant difference among soil types, as nutrient amount changes a lot among depths in every soil type.

How should I include soil depth in the model? Alternatively, which kind of ANOVA would you suggest if not considering plot as a random factor?